# Undefined reference to `FT_Done_MM_Var'

Tags: python, anaconda, ros

I install anaconda2, ros and opencv3.4 in Ubuntu16.04, and when I `catkin_make` a ros workspace, there is an error:
`/home/zqk/anaconda2/lib/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined reference to 'FT_Done_MM_Var'`.
I've tried many ways to solve, but still cannot solve it.
Can anyone help me? thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

I hope I can help you! I solved this!

I met the same problem when I installed pcl1.9.

> [ 45%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/pcl_mesh_sampling
>
> /home/ifcoxs/anaconda3/lib/libfontconfig.so.1：对‘FT_Done_MM_Var’未定义的引用
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   tools/CMakeFiles/pcl_mesh_sampling.dir/build.make:314: recipe for
>   target 'bin/pcl_mesh_sampling' failed make[2]: ***
>   [bin/pcl_mesh_sampling] Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3221: recipe for
>   target 'tools/CMakeFiles/pcl_mesh_sampling.dir/all' failed make[1]:
>   *** [tools/CMakeFiles/pcl_mesh_sampling.dir/all] Error 2 make[1]: *** 正在等待未完成的任务....

After troubleshooting, I found that this library file is a problem (libfontconfig.so.1).It has two paths and the versions are inconsistent.

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ ll |grep libfontconfig.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       23 4月   6  2018 libfontconfig.so -> libfontconfig.so.1.10.1
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       23 5月  31 16:04 libfontconfig.so.1 -> libfontconfig.so.1.10.1
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   281984 4月   6  2018 libfontconfig.so.1.10.1
~/anaconda3/lib$ ll | grep libfontconfig.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 ifcoxs ifcoxs       23 5月  31 20:17 libfontconfig.so -> libfontconfig.so.1.11.1*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 ifcoxs ifcoxs       23 5月  31 20:17 libfontconfig.so.1 -> libfontconfig.so.1.11.1*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ifcoxs ifcoxs   324384 5月  31 20:17 libfontconfig.so.1.11.1*
```

So I do it two steps:

```
1.
copy the file from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu to ~/anaconda3/lib
2.
~/anaconda3/lib$ ln -s libfontconfig.so.1.10.1 libfontconfig.so.1
~/anaconda3/lib$ ln -s libfontconfig.so.1.10.1 libfontconfig.so

The final display is as follows:
~/anaconda3/lib$ ll |grep libfontconfig
-rw-r--r--  1 ifcoxs ifcoxs   494654 5月  31 20:17 libfontconfig.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ifcoxs ifcoxs     1252 5月  31 20:17 libfontconfig.la*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 ifcoxs ifcoxs       23 6月  13 21:19 libfontconfig.so -> libfontconfig.so.1.10.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 ifcoxs ifcoxs       23 6月  13 21:19 libfontconfig.so.1 -> libfontconfig.so.1.10.1
-rw-r--r--  1 ifcoxs ifcoxs   281984 6月  13 21:17 libfontconfig.so.1.10.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ifcoxs ifcoxs   324384 5月  31 20:17 libfontconfig.so.1.11.1*
```

Comment: The files may also be in /usr/lib64